# Property of Lebesgue integrable function proof verification

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

Suppose $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $X$ and define:

\begin{align*}
X_{n}=\{x \in X: |f(x)|\geq n\}
\end{align*}

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\lambda(X_{n})=0$

**Proof:**
Since $f$ is integrable, then $|f|$ is also integrable. Consider the following inequality:

$$|f|\chi_{X_{n}} \leq |f|$$ Using properties of Lebesgue integral then:

$$\int |f|\chi_{X_{n}} d\lambda \leq \int |f| d\lambda < \infty$$ So

$$0 \leq\int n\chi_{X_{n}}d\lambda=n\lambda(X_{n})\leq\int|f|\chi_{X_{n}}d\lambda<\infty$$

Taking limit as $n \to \infty$ and using Lebesgue increasing convergence:

$$0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} n\lambda(X_{n}) \leq \int |f| \lim_{n \to \infty} \chi_{X_{n}} \to 0$$

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Is $X$ sub-set of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: X is a subset of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step is not correct. The sequence is not increasing; it is decreasing. It is better to finish the proof using DCT.